How can I use Windows/Android accent color in .NET Maui?
I want to use the Accent color that user have set in the system settings, as the main theme of my app. I mean the
Accent Color in Windows or the
Color palette in Android
I'm not sure if there's a way to use the Windows.UI.ViewManagement and something like this (code suggested by ms Copilot):
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
// Inside the Page Class:
var uiSettings = new UISettings();
var accentColor = uiSettings.GetColorValue(UIColorType.Accent);


You can use Windows/Android accent color by the following code:
        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
#if WINDOWS
            var uiSettings = new Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UISettings();
            var color = uiSettings.GetColorValue(Windows.UI.ViewManagement.UIColorType.Accent);
            var mauicolor = Color.Parse(color.ToString());
            (sender as Button).BackgroundColor = mauicolor;
#elif ANDROID
            var value = new Android.Util.TypedValue();
            Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorAccent, value, true);
            var contexwrapper = new AndroidX.AppCompat.View.ContextThemeWrapper(Android.App.Application.Context.ApplicationContext, Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDeviceDefault);
            contexwrapper.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Android.Resource.Attribute.ColorAccent, value, true);
            var color = value.Data;
            var mauicolor = new Android.Graphics.Color(color).ToColor();
            (sender as Button).BackgroundColor = mauicolor;
#endif
        }

Note: I tested it on the windows and worked but I didn't find any where can set the system accent on my android device and simulator. So I refer to this case: Get Android system accent color (Android 10 System color accent), and convert the java code to c#.

Hi. Thanks for your answer. How can I use Windows.UI... and Android.Util...? When I add it in my project, I get the error "The type or namespace Windows could not be found." There is no such package in nuget either. In what namespace are those located?

Did you copy the code #if Windows? You can just copy the full code and run it with ignoring the error. @SepehrHekmatRad

The namespace has be contained in the default platform sdk. And the Conditional compilation will make the error disappear. @SepehrHekmatRad
